# swapping string in c using pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

Need help

this is my code

```
void swapstringfun()
{
   int i=0,j=0;
   char *str=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
   char *mystr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
   system("cls");
   printf("Please enter first string :\t");
   scanf("%s",str);
   printf("Please enter second string :\t");
   scanf("%s",mystr);
   while(*(str+i)!='\0' && *(mystr+i)!='\0')
   {
     *(str+i) ^=*(mystr+i);
     *(mystr+i) ^=*(str+i);
     *(str+i) ^=*(mystr+i);
     i++;
   }
   printf("%s swapped to %s",str,mystr);
   getch();
   main();
}
```

I wrote the above code to swap the string using XOR operator. The problem with this code is. when my input is lets say.. **RAJESH** and **ASHISH**. Then, it shows output **ASHISH** and **RAJESH**. And, that is expected.

But, when input is let say.. **ABHISHEK** and **CODER** .Then, output is **CODERHEK** and **ABHIS**. But, the expected output is **CODER** and **ABHISHEK**. Anyone help me to solve this problem. I will appreciate.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Using xor is a rather silly way to swap two values. Using a temporary variable is both safer and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate and swap until you reach the end of the shorter string

```
while(*(str+i)!='\0' && *(mystr+i)!='\0')
```

(or both, if the lengths are equal). To iterate until you reach the end of the longer string, you need an `||` instead of the `&&` **and be sure that 1. both pointers point to large enough memory blocks, and 2. the shorter string ends with enough 0 bytes**. So you should `calloc` the memory, not `malloc`.

However, you should swap the pointers, really,

```
char *tmp = str;
str = mystr;
mystr = tmp;
```

Comment: @coders But, as indicated by the bolded text, that is dangerous.

Comment: ok got it. i will go through the concept of `malloc` and `calloc`. I mean, their differences and usage.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to swap the terminating 0, as its part of what is called a string in C.

The 0 is the stopper element in the character array, describing the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to XOR the entire length of both strings. Since in your second example, the strings are different lengths, your algorithm won't work.

This is the statement you'll have to reconsider:

```
while(*(str+i)!='\0' && *(mystr+i)!='\0')
```